# Sync data to server in background like dropbox , evernote does

Tags: android, synchronization

I am building a photo app in android where user will click no of photos and send it to server and if internet goes out in the middle of uploading it will save the photo in sqlite database.
Now i want that photos to automatically uploaded to server whenever the internet came back even if the app is not running. Can anyone suggest how it can be achieved?

I saw dropbox automatically upload the photos even the app is not running. I want similar functionality. Please suggest a way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

all you have to do is run a background service which will check if your database table has rows in it then if exists it will continue the upload and delete every row after it's completion from the table

EDIT

your service can't remain working if your app is fully closed from the Manager, I suggest you use the "Syncing to the Cloud" functionality check [Here](http://developer.android.com/training/cloudsync/index.html)  it contains the neccessary mechanism Majority of the apps use it DropBox also I think

Comment: but how to run that service? Even if the app is closed? Can you give me some examples?

Comment: check the link for Sync in the cloud

Comment: ok i will look into it. Do i need any server side work in order to do the same?

Comment: yes you will need a cloud storage like google drive or your own Hosting plan, and you need to register to Android Backup Service in order to Backup user data, accept the answer if it helped thnx